# Get array values in Truffle console

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, geth-debugging, console

Is there a way to print the values of an array in my contract to a console (using truffle or geth for example)?

Suppose this is my contract:

```
contract MetaCoin {

    uint256[] public someNumbers;

    function writeNumber(uint256 num) public {
      someNumbers.push(num);
    }
...
```

Now, I managed to get one value of `someNumbers`, but not all of them through

```
> meta.someNumbers.call(0)
> BigNumber { s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 123 ] }
```

Note that I made an instance of the MetaCoin contract first with `MetaCoin.deployed().then(a => {meta = a})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you want a method to get each added number and that can be done just by specifying the variable as `public`, a getter is automatically created.

But you also need to know how many items are in there, a new method must be defined.

Let's consider this contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MetaCoin {

    uint256[] public someNumbers;

    function writeNumber(uint256 num) public {
        someNumbers.push(num);
    }


    function getSomeNumbers() public view returns(uint256[]) {
        return someNumbers;
    }

    function getSomeNumbersLength() public view returns(uint256) {
        return someNumbers.length;
    }
}
```

You can call `writeNumber(item)` to add numbers to your array.

#### `getSomeNumbers() public view returns(uint256[])`

In order to retrieve them you can use the method `getSomeNumbers()` which will return the complete array of items. This however is not a good practice because `n` items will be added to your array and you will return `n` items. The number of items can be infinitely large, thus your node will not be able to return the complete array.

Another method is more scalable

#### getSomeNumbersLength() public view returns(uint256)

You can retrieve the count of the items and get them one by one. Calling `getSomeNumbersLength()` will return the length of the array and you can retrieve the items one by one by calling `someNumbers(uint256 index)`

### Web3

Going back to how you do this in web3, you will need to call this in 2 parts

```
length = await meta.getSomeNumbersLength.call()

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    item = await meta.someNumbers.call(i)
    // Do things with the `item`
}
```

Experiment with this on remix ide
https://gist.github.com/cleanunicorn/0025a060e7a5657a5e19855d11d36507

Comment: Both options give the values which is fine, I was looking for a more interactive solution (like a command line tool that let's one inspect contract variables or a feature in Ganache). But this does the job for now

Answer (score 1):

Yes you achieve the this by adding a getter function as such:

```
...
uint256[] public someNumbers;

function writeNumber(uint256 num) public {
    someNumbers.push(num);
}

function getNumbers() public view returns(uint256[]) {
    return someNumbers;
}
...
```

You can test is with the following testcode in metacoin.js:

```
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
  it("should get an array of uint256's", async function() {
    var meta = await MetaCoin.deployed();
    await meta.writeNumber(123);
    await meta.writeNumber(321);
    await meta.writeNumber(231);

    var numberAray = await meta.getNumbers();

    assert.equal(await numberAray.length, 3, "Array did not return as expected..");
  });
});
```

Comment: yes, that's how to work with it in JS I guess - is there a way to loop through the numbers right from the console? Just would be much more interactive than having to run a script each time. When I do `truffle(development)> meta.someNumbers` I get 
    `{ [Function]
    call: [Function],
    sendTransaction: [Function],
    request: [Function: bound ],
    estimateGas: [Function] }` 
which looks like there is more I can do with this

Comment: Yes, you can: 
```var meta;```
```MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(contract){meta = contract})```
```meta.writeNumber(321)```
```meta.writeNumber(123)```
```meta.getNumbers()``` 

then it returns the array which you can loop trough!

Comment: Just in case if you actually want to loop through the array you need the add the following steps: 
```var numbers;``` ```meta.getNumbers().then(function(numberArr){numbers= numberArr })``` ```numbers.forEach(function(d){console.log(d)})```